# getting fetch error in rtk query even after successful request

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, rtk-query

I am using a delete mutation to remove an items. Though the request goes well, it does delete the item but it returns an error `{"status":"FETCH_ERROR","error":"TypeError: Network request failed"}` instead of a success 204 code (as defined in my backend).

I don't know what part goes wrong, so here is the relevant code;

```
addserviceDetails: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ body, method }) => ({
        url: "/my/end/point",
        method, // method is provided dynamically, for now, it is DELETE, (for PUT and POST it works fine)
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["services"], // used to refetch services but note that the error is from delete request.
    }),
```

then in my component;

```
  const [deleteserviceMutation, { isLoading }] = useAddserviceDetailsMutation();



 const deleteService = async () => {
    try {
      await deleteserviceMutation({
        body: { service_id: id },
        method: "DELETE",
      }).unwrap();
      showToast("info", "Service Removed"); // this toast is never shown even after successful request as it returns an error.
    } catch (err) {
      errorHandler(err);
    }
  };
```

I also checked the server, it is fine on that side, there is no error (and it is normal as the error is FETCH_ERROR).

**EDIT**

Here is the response from the mutation;

```
 authApiSlice/executeMutation/rejected
 INFO    dispatching {"type":"authApiSlice/executeMutation/rejected","payload":{"status":"FETCH_ERROR","error":"TypeError: Network request failed"},"meta":{"baseQueryMeta":{"request":{"url":"http://10.0.2.2:8000/my/end/point","credentials":"same-origin","headers":{"map":{"authorization":"Token token","content-type":"application/json"}},"method":"DELETE","mode":null,"signal":{},"referrer":null,"bodyUsed":false,"_bodyInit":"{\"service_id\":121}","_bodyText":"{\"service_id\":121}"}},"RTK_autoBatch":true,"arg":{"type":"mutation","endpointName":"endpoint","originalArgs":{"body":{"service_id":121},"method":"DELETE"},"track":true},"requestId":"qkiI1McsG41b7rV2Xr3TI","rejectedWithValue":true,"requestStatus":"rejected","aborted":false,"condition":false},"error":{"message":"Rejected"}}
```

Comment: `FETCH_ERROR` means that something on browser level went wrong. Take a look into your Browser Devtools, especially the Network Tab.

Comment: @phry I am not able to connect to the debugger. It is giving error, console.assert is not a function. After checking on internet, it seems to be an issue with reanimated.

Comment: I added a logging middleware to check the network request. Will add the response to the question

Comment: Also I am using another delete request the same way in my app to delete the account and that works fine. The only difference between these two is this one also invalidates a tag to refetch the data and deleteaccount only deletes the acount (which doesn't seem to be a reason for the request to reject).

Comment: `FETCH_ERROR` really comes from inside `fetch`, it's not an RTK Query error - so it would occur if you were sending off a blank `fetch` statement just as well.

Comment: Not getting any thing clear to fix this bug. As a workaround for now, I changed the success code (204) to an error code on backend as errors are properly handled by frontend and when the delete request goes it shows the relevant message. Thus whether it is an actual error or the things worked fine, it will show the relevant message.